# Extracting functions arguments using RegExp (PREG)

Tags: sql, regex, pcre

Consider the following function arguments (they are already extracted of the function):

```
Monkey,"Blue Monkey", "Red, blue and \"Green'",  'Red, blue and "Green\''
```

Is there a way to extract arguments to get the following array ouput using regexp and stripping white spaces:

```
[Monkey, "Blue Monkey", "Red, blue and \"Green'", 'Red, blue and "Green\'']
```

I'm stuck using this RegExp which is not permisive enough:

```
/(("[^"]+"|[^\s,]+))/g
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks a little nasty but it works:

```
/(?:"(?:[^\x5C"]+|\x5C(?:\x5C\x5C)*[\x5C"])*"|'(?:[^\x5C']+|\x5C(?:\x5C\x5C)*[\x5C'])*'|[^"',]+)+/g
```

I used `\x5C` instead of the plain backslash character `\` as too much of those can be confusing.

This regular expression consists of the parts:

1. `"(?:[^\x5C"]+|\x5C(?:\x5C\x5C)*[\x5C"])*"` matches double quoted string declarations
2. `'(?:[^\x5C']+|\x5C(?:\x5C\x5C)*[\x5C'])*'` matches single quoted string declarations
3. `[^"',]+` matches anything else (except commas).

The parts of `"(?:[^\x5C"]+|\x5C(?:\x5C\x5C)*[\x5C"])*"` are:

1. `[^\x5C"]+` matches anything except the backspace and quote character
2. `\x5C(?:\x5C\x5C)*[\x5C"]` matches proper escape sequences like `\"`, `\\`, `\\\"`, `\\\\`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're seeking, nor yet how to do this in SQL, but isn't something like this sufficient:

(Using python as an example)

```
import re
x = '''Monkey, "Blue Monkey", "Red, blue and "Green\\"", 'Red, blue and "Green\\'\''''
l = re.split(',\s*',x)
print x
for a in l:
    print a
```

Comment: This regexp wont work for items that are not separated with whitespace.
Sorry forgot to mention it.

Comment: Just change the ',\s+' to ',\s*' to make the spacing optional